# Accessing a Module Imported from Another Module's Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

**The Issue:**

I want to use a module that has been imported from within a different module with it's function.

**What I want to achieve:**

main.py

```
import differentFile

print (differentFile.functionName.os.getcwd())
```

differentFile.py

```
def functionName():
    import os
```

**What I have tried:**

Pretty much the above, but it doesn't work as functionName as no function os.
I have managed to achieve the above without using the function, but I need to use the function.

Comment: I don't see the point of doing this. Why not import `os` in `main.py`?

Comment: Not possible. Functions don't have access to their local variables (which a module imported in the function would be), as said local variables only exist within any given invocation of the function and don't belong to the function itself.

Comment: @BallpointBen is there any way to make it global then?

Comment: Import the module yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately, for this specific use case it isn't what I wanted to do :(

Comment: @Aiyush: do you try to get the directory of the differentFile.py?

Comment: It is in the same directory as the main file. @ndclt

Comment: the result of `getcwd` will be the same from the both file. I don't see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I used the os module as an example @ndclt , in my code I have a dynamically created module whose path isn't the default path so I was to adjust the sys path in the module and load it through that module, since it won't exist at initial run time, this is the best way to do it. So, I hope that this partially explains why. If you have any suggestions I would really appreciate that, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Aiyush: it seems still weird to me that you need to create a new module dynamically. You should maybe edit your post or do another one with something closer to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do this, you can simply import os in main